# Java Swing: how to shade a game gui after the match has finished

Tags: java, swing

In a board game we are developping in Java we would like the gui to be overshadowed when the game is finished. We have a Jframe in which there is JPanel with the board on which there are some colored pawns and boxes (JButtons) and we would like  that everything becomes a sort of black and white and grey. Is there an authomatic method in Java to do this in Java Components?

Answer (score 2):

There are several different kinds of panes to look at that could achieve this, or something similar, if you are using Swing (which I assume from the tag, that you are).
You could use a Glass Pane. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane
glass panes could be thought of as like a CSS overlay. They dis-allow interaction with components behind them.

Also, take a look at JXLayers and JLayers, they allow you to modify the way components are actually painted.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Override paintComponent() (Or if you have some components added to the container it's better to override paintComponents() method).

Call

```
super.paintComponent(g);
Color semiColor=new Color(0,0,0,128);//the last param represents alpha
g.fillRect(semiColor);
```